# struts2 forgot password code

Tags: jsp, struts2

i need the code in struts2 for forgot pass word.i have a jsp where the user can enter the username.then i will get dat user name in action class.and with that user name i will select password and email from database and i dont know the reat code that how to send email.

my jsp is:

my action class is:

```
public class UserFormControlAction extends ActionSupport
{



    private String fusername;



    public String getFusername() {
        return fusername;
    }

    public void setFusername(String fusername) {
        this.fusername =fusername;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be specific where you are facing problem.SO is a community which is ready to help if you are in some trouble, but do not expect code,better do a Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very broad question. Can give you hint and some reference

Hint : you can  use [javaMail API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

reference : [How to send e-mail through java](http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/jeetutorials/sendingemail/) , thats some tutorial and you should be able to get past your problem.